# What are the differences between Launch URL and App URL?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-express

What is the difference between `App URL` and `Launch URL` from `ASP.NET Core`?

[image]

With these settings, I can access my app, both over `HTTP` on port 4099 and over `HTTPS` on port `44363`, but first it launches on `HTTPS`.  I'm using VS 2017.  If I use the same URL for App and Launch I get:

> An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of `dotnet.exe` which is hosting your application. One or more errors occurred.

If I remove `Launch URL` and keep `App URL` with `HTTPS` I get the same error.

What is the difference between them and how do I redirect every `HTTP` request to `HTTPS`?
Microsoft is not helping right now: [link to microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl)

Comment: IIS Express has trouble with SSL is the port isn't between 44300 and 44399. I have no idea why, but it has bitten me before!

Comment: @DavidG In this case it is between 44300 and 44399. It is 44363. It was auto-generated on Enable SSL check.

Comment: Yes, but you said you kept the App URL with HTTPS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as i can tell:

- Launch Url is the url you host your dotnet core application on and to which port the kestrel server is listening.
- Websettings, AppUrl is the url IIS is listening to. IIS (which is basically a reverse proxy here) will  forward all the http request comming from the AppUrl to the Launch URL.

If you remove the Launch URL kestrel has no port to listen to, and will throw an error on startup, or fallback to port 5000.

Comment: will throw an error or fallback to port 5000, what now?

Comment: @Pascal most probably will fallback to a random port in visual studio but to 5000 is kestrel default.

Comment: Kestrell over here hosted my app using the applicationUrl. I'm not using any IIS.