# Controllers.cs works on diffrent address - .net core angular app from visual studio template

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-core, get

I created a new project in .Net Core and Agnular from visual studio template and I cant get data from controller. It works with controller genereted from template WeatherController.cs but not with my own. I mean it works when I call controller like that:

> https://localhost:5001/home/getData/1

but application starts at 5002 and method from weatherController also works with 5002. I don't understand why one controller work on 5002 and another on 5001.
Could anyone can explain me how to configure this propertly or send me some source to understand how this is works. Thanks

**Configuration**:

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49323",
      "sslPort": 44374
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:5002",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**Controller**:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetData/{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetData(int id)
    {
        return "ok";
    }
```

[image]

**sevice.ts**

//baseURL - https://localhost:5002

```
return this.http.get<any>(this.baseURL + 'home/GetData/' + id)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      );


http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'weatherforecast').subscribe(result => {
  this.forecasts = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
```

1st one works only when I change 5002 to 5001 but second one works on 5002...

https://localhost:5001/home/getData/1 - OK

https://localhost:5002/home/getData/1 - NOT OK

https://localhost:5002/weatherforecast - OK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Launch URL and App URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650194/what-are-the-differences-between-launch-url-and-app-url)

Comment: IIS will forward all the http request coming from the AppUrl to the Launch URL.

Comment: Not really because I dont know to solve this... I updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to include `/home` path to `ClientApp\proxy.conf.js` file

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/home"
   ],
    target: "https://localhost:5001",
    secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

This is [angular config for proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxy-multiple-entries)

Comment: It works. Thank you. I didn't have to add it before when doing a project from template. I understand that every new controller I have to add there?

Comment: Not sure what is the best practice here. Maybe add every path, maybe use original API URL in httpClient or maybe something else